# User's edit button disabled in custom list

Tags: list, custom, edit, sharepoint-list

I am having problems with SharePoint custom list. Everything was fine until they asked me to add a new item in the list. Now a specific user can't edit any of the items in the list since the edit button was disabled. He belongs to the same group but the issue where the edit button was disabled is limited to him only.

This is what appears if he wants to edit an item.
[image]

Comment: Does that item have any item level permission setup which might be removing the edit access.

Comment: Also can you try to check the ECB (drop down next to title) to check if user can edit the item or not.

Comment: I didn't put any content approval for this list and no item level permissions too. Also this happened quite suddenly, he was able to edit it before.

Comment: What about ECB .. can user edit from there ?

Comment: ECB? I am not familiar with the term.

Comment: The SharePoint group has been given "Edit" access. Also other people in the group can edit the item except for him. I have also asked him to try using "Compatibility View" but to no avail.

Comment: Refer this url for EBC block - http://www.sharepoint24x7.com/2011/07/21/introducing-edit-control-block-ecb/

Comment: Can you check the permission for that user -- select item --> Item tab --> Shared With -->Advanced. Do do see that user / group having permission on that item.

Comment: Also can you check from other browser / machine for that user.

Comment: Can you check the site permissions and see if the edit permission of the user has been removed outside the group

Comment: my list has no EBC. :/ don't know why. maybe because I placed a sort in the view?

Comment: The user is included in the group that has permission to edit the list. Seen in "Shared With"

Comment: Did you try removing the user from the group and adding him back again ?

Comment: didn't try that. he is tagged in some of the items in the list, i'm afraid i might mess up the list if i remove him.

Comment: He did say he can add new items to the list, only he can't edit any of them.

Comment: Try adding him to a full control group as well to see if he's able to edit. You don't have to remove him from the current group to do that. After this , remove him from the full control group and check again

Comment: Hi, upgrading his access allowed him to edit items again. Thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

It seems some cache kind of issue. Just ask him to try from other machine or restart the browser. Or just give me permission directly to check if he can edit than. And what kind of new item you added? Try deleting that new item and then check if nothing works.